# Timer method inside a class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

First of all an introduction to my development environment:

```
OS: Windows.
SDK: Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.
```

Earlier today I was facing the problem of trying to define a Timer inside a class. My class is interfacing a Python embedded module and a C++ backend, My problem is that I need to receive some time event on the python module. Also it is important to notice that there will be only one instance of this class.

The main problem is that when I define a timer using:

```
/* Null, 0, mseconds, CALLBACK_METHOD */
SetTimer(NULL, 0, 100, (TIMERPROC) OnTimer);
```

The method activated on the timer event (OnTimer) needs to be a static method on my Class (and then I cannot access any non-static methods or variables inside that class).

Reading some code on codeproject I have found: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4817/How-to-use-SetTimer-with-callback-to-a-non-static

I have a similar implementation but without the lines:

```
void * CSleeperThread::pObject;
```

and

```
CSleeperThread *pSomeClass = (CSleeperThread*)pObject; // cast the void pointer
pSomeClass->TimerProc(hwnd, uMsg, idEvent, dwTime); // call non-static function
```

Is this the only way to implement the functionality I'm looking for? Is there an easier way I may have skipped on my information gathering process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a static map of your Class object:

```
static std::map<UINT_PTR, CMyClass*> m_CMyClassMap; //declaration
```

At the time of object creation insert the object in this map:

```
CMyClass myClassObj;
CMyClassMap.insert(std::pair<int, CMyClass*>(0, &myClassObj));
```

Now you can use it in static methods to access its non static members.

```
int a = m_CMyClassMap[0]->m_someNonStaticMember;
```

Answer (score 0):

So long as there is only one instance of this class, there is an easy (if somewhat ugly) solution: Declare your class object and then store a pointer to it in a global object. E.g.,

```
MyClass myObject;
MyClass* self = &myObject;
```

Then inside your static member, you can use self->myMethod() or self->myData to refer to non static items.